# PHP SimpleXML add CSS to SVG

Tags: php, svg, simplexml

I am trying to add a def element inside an existing svg but the inserted node data is a string instead of css markup like this(contains "&lt\;" and the whole node value is enclosed in double quote):

```
"<defs xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">&lt;style type="text/css"&gt\;@font-face {font-family: DaimlerCS-Demi;src: url('../fonts/CorporateS/CorporateS-Demi.otf');}&lt\;/style&gt;</defs>"
```

How do we make add a css node for defs in the svg properly? This is my existing php code:

```
$data = trim(file_get_contents('php://input'));
$svg = new SimpleXMLElement($data);
$svg->registerXPathNamespace('svg', 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg');
$defContent = <<<EOF
<style type="text/css">@font-face {font-family: DaimlerCS-Demi;src: 
url('../fonts/CorporateS/CorporateS-Demi.otf');}</style>
EOF;
$def = $svg->addChild("defs", $defContent);
$svg = $svg->asXML();
$filePath = "./res/" . base64_encode(time()) . ".svg";
file_put_contents($filePath, $svg);
```

Also, if possible, how do we make it to add the node as the first child instead of inserted them as last

Answer (score 0):

I had to add the style node just like the way I add the def:

```
$def = $svg->addChild('def');
$style = $def->addChild('style', $defContent);
$style->addAttribute('type', 'text/css');
```